# Query com 3 condições AND não funciona a última condição

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Gostaria de fazer uma query em duas tabelas que leva em consideração 3 critérios, porém não está apresentando o resultado esperado.

```
Select viaturas.vtr_numero
From viaturas, despacho_ocorrencias
Where 
viaturas.parado_manutencao='NÃO' and 
viaturas.parado_utilizacao='NÃO' and
despacho_ocorrencias.fechar_despacho='NÃO'
group by viaturas.vtr_numero
```

Nesta query acima eu gostaria de mostrasse somente o número das viaturas que não tivessem em manutenção, que não tivessem paradas de utilização e com despacho em aberto (neste caso com flag 'SIM'), porém a última condição não está funcionando pois está aparecem as com flag 'SIM' e 'NÃO'.

Será que existe algo errado na query? se eu faço as duas primeiras condições está normal, coloco junto a última condição o resultado não condiz.

Comment: pode mostrar com estão os dados na tabela? não ficou muito claro

Comment: Marcelo seria o ideal você colocar a estrutura da tabela e um exemplo da saída esperada, assim seria mais fácil lhe ajudar

Comment: Xará, qual é a relação entre as tabelas `viaturas` e `despacho_ocorrencias`? Você tá fazendo um produto cartesiano das duas tabelas.

Comment: como o @MarceloShinitiUchimura comentou, está usando duas tabelas sem estabelecer a relação entre elas (com `join` ou no `where`), então faz o cartesiado, combinando os resultados

Comment: Não entendi o porque desta cláusula GROUP BY se você não utiliza nenhuma função de agregação.
Supondo que quando você diz "com despacho em aberto (neste caso com flag 'SIM')" esteja se referindo a outro campo que não o despacho_ocorrencias.fechar_despacho especificado na query então teria apenas que substituir pelo campo correto. Note que você está fazendo um CROSS JOIN, ou produto cartesiano das tabelas viaturas e despacho_ocorrencias.

Comment: Pelos comentários está faltando linkar as duas tabelas, vou fazer testar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou ajustar o `join`.

Você está dando select em duas tabelas sem "linkar" as mesmas.

Insira uma condição `viaturas.CampoRelacionado = despacho_ocorrencias.CampoRelacionado` para evitar um select da combinação das mesmas.

Como disseram nos comentários, não está fazendo sentido o `group by` visto que não há agregação na query.

Comment: Realmente está faltando linkar as duas tabelas, vou fazer testar. obrigado